# IELTS test result - Does the UK need the original, and is it returned?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, ielts, language-test

While applying for Tier 2 UK visa do we need to submit an original copy of IELTS test result, as only a single copy of the test result is provided to the candidate? And is that copy returned, once a decision is made regarding the visa application?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they need the original, and yes, it is returned.

Comment: Do you have any reference?

Comment: I can look for it online, but this is based on my own experience.